# Find Index of SINGLE odd / even number in array

Tags: javascript

So I was doing some challenges on codewars.com and came across the following challenge (I managed to close the browser so could not submit my answer and therefore could not see the best possible solutions).

Given an array of at least 3 integers, all the elements in the array are either even or oneven EXCEPT for 1 element -->

`[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]`

OR:

`[160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]`

All the elements are either even or oneven except for one where it is the other way around. Return the element that is the odd one out, so:

`findOutlier([2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]) //should return 11`

`findOutlier([160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]) //should return 160`

I got a working solution but there has to be a better way of doing this.. My solution:

````
function findOutlier(integers){
  let evenCount = 0;
  let oddCount = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
    if(integers[i] % 2 === 0) {
      evenCount += 1;
    } else {
      oddCount += 1
    }
  }
  let idx = integers.find(function(index) {
    if(evenCount > 2) {
      return index % 2 === 1
    } else {
      return index % 2 === 0
    }
  })
  return idx
}

```
````

Comment: The title states *Find **Index** ...* but the above approach returns **value**. What's the actual intention?

Comment: Value... I'm sorry. It was late in the evening, my bad hehe.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to iterate the first 3 numbers of the array.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

You are iterating through the array twice. You should only iterate once. You can do this by setting the values in the first loop:

```
let evenCount = 0;
let oddCount = 0;
let evenNumber = 0;
let oddNumber = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if(integers[i] % 2 === 0) {
      evenCount++;
      evenNumber = integers[i];
    } else {
      oddCount++;
      oddNumber = integers[i];
    }
}

return evenCount > 1 ? oddNumber : evenNumber;
```

Comment: Awesome, good point about only needing to iterate through the first 3 elements. Thanks a lot for your alternate solution!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in dustytrash's answer you need only check the first 3 items to find out if you are hunting for odd or even values.

There are also some optimizations you can add to reduce the number of statements and clauses.

Rather than use two variables in the first loop to locate even or odd you can use just one and count up for odd and down for even. Also using a while loop is slightly more performant in this situation so we get the opening lines as

```
function findOutlier(items){
    var oddEven = 0, i = 3;
    while (i--) { 
        oddEven += items[i] % 2 ? -1 : 1;
    }
    // more code to follow
```

Once out of the loop `oddEven` will be less than zero if we are looking of even;

Rather than use a statement and two constants to check each item for the remainder we can set that before the search.

```
    oddEven = oddEven > 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

Then we can use `Array.find` to locate the item returning it directly rather than waste time assigning it to a variable to return as you did.

```
    return items.find(val => val % 2 === oddEven);
}
```

The whole thing will look like

```
function findOutlier(items){
    var oddEven = 0, i = 3;
    while (i--) { oddEven += items[i] % 2 ? -1 : 1 }
    oddEven = oddEven > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return items.find(val => val % 2 === oddEven);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution! I'll play around with it a bit to really grasp what's going on. Again TY!